# Knockout Mapping Object Not Returned by Durandal Viewmodel

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js, durandal

I am planning to use the Knockout Mapping plugin to map data returned from ajax calls to the viewmodel under the Durandal framework. However, I did not know how to return the mapped object so that the view can use it. Here's my code for the viewmodel login.js:

```
define(function (require) {
    var system = require('durandal/system'),
          app = require('durandal/app'),
          ko = require('knockout'),
          komapping = require('komapping'),
          deferred = $.Deferred(),
          loginOptionsUrl = '/json/loginOptions.json',
          loginInterfaceData = {};

ko.mapping = komapping;

return {

activate: function(){
     var request = $.getJSON(loginOptionsUrl)
          .done(function(data){
          loginInterfaceData = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
          system.log(loginInterfaceData); //Do a check here; loginInterfaceData contains all the right data
          deferred.resolve();  
          });
     return deferred.promise();
},
loginInterfaceData: loginInterfaceData; //However, the view gets an empty object
```

As you can see, the object returned from ko.mapping is assigned to loginInterfaceData, which I return to the view. However, when I examine the loginInterfaceData object returned by 'viewmodels/login' under the Web Inspector, it is an empty object. The only reasoning I can come up with is that the viewmodel returns loginInterfaceData before the mapping is finished. However, I have no idea how to prevent that from happening.

Any ideas/advice will be most appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you return a reference to inner `loginInterfaceData`, but in your `activate` function you reassign that variable, so previously returned `loginInterfaceData` will always be an empty object. What you can do is return a getter function for your `loginInterfaceData` like this:

```
...
getLoginInterfaceData: function() {
  return loginInterfaceData;
}
...
```

And in your calling code, after `activate` is done, just call `getLoginInterfaceData()`.
Here is simple example:

```js
function foo() {
    var bar = {};
    return {
        setBar : function(x) {
            bar = x;
        },
        bar: bar,
        getBar: function() {
            return bar;
        }
    }
}

var f = foo();
f.setBar(5);
console.log(f.bar); // logs empty object
console.log(f.getBar()); // logs value of inner foo.bar
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem lies in returning the `loginInterfaceData` object *before* the `activate` function is invoked, causing the view to receive the original empty object. My solution ends up being to bind `loginInterfaceData` to empty data first, then updating it once the data has been received via Ajax. Like this:

```
(...)    

ko.mapping = komapping;
loginInterfaceData = ko.mapping.fromJS({}); //instead of assigning loginInterfaceData = {}, I use KO Mapping with an ampty JSON object

(...)

return {

activate: function(){
            return $.ajax({
                url: loginOptionsUrl,
                contentType: 'application/json',
            }).done(function(data) {
                ko.mapping.fromJS(data, loginInterfaceData);//so here, instead of mapping for the first time, I remap/update it
            });

},
loginInterfaceData: loginInterfaceData; //at this point, loginInterfaceData is still empty object but will be updated/remap once ajax call is successful
```

Hope this helps someone who runs into the same issue as I did. Cheers.